# The embeddings $S^{6} \to S^{7}$ and $S^{7}\to S^{8}$

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Is the standard smooth structure of $S^{7}$ the only structure for which each of the following canonical  embedding is  an smooth embedding?:

1)$S^{6}\to S^{7}$

2)$S^{7}\to S^{8}$

Comment: What do you mean by "canonical embedding" precisely? $S^6$ always embed in a smooth 7-manifold as a boundary of a ball contained in a chart.

Comment: @MarcoGolla I mean $x\to(x,0)$.

Comment: I don't think this is well-defined: how do you ensure that this is smooth?

Comment: Anyway, this discussion (and the references therein) seems to answer the second question in the positive: http://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/ar25

Comment: @MarcoGolla What is not well defined? As your second statement: My question is the same as yours: Is this embedding an smooth map where the smooth structure of $S^{7}$ is exotic?

Comment: @MarcoGolla thank you for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will interpret (the negation of) your questions in the following way.

> Let $n>5$ and consider the topological embedding of the equator $S^{n-1}$ in a *topological* $S^n$. 
>   1) Is there an exotic smooth structure on $S^n$ such that, for the round structure on $S^{n-1}$ the embedding is smooth? 
>   2) Does any exotic smooth $S^{n-1}$ embed smoothly in the standard $S^{n}$?

These kind of problems are usually solved by the [$h$-cobordism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-cobordism#Precise_statement_of_the_h-cobordism_theorem) and its applications.

**1)** Yes (that is, *your* first question has a negative answer).
Consider a smooth structure $X$ on $S^n$ and let $S^{n-1}\hookrightarrow X$ be a smooth embedding that bounds a standard ball $B$ in a chart $U$ for $X$. There is a homeomorphism $X\to S^n$ that restricts to a diffeomorphism of $B$ onto the lower hemisphere (*e.g.* because $X$ is a [twisted sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere#Twisted_spheres)). This shows that you can map $S^{n-1}$ into any exotic $S^n$ as the "equator".

**2)** No (that is, *your* second question has a positive answer).
This is a [generalisation of the Schoenflies problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem#Generalizations): if $S^{n-1}$ is a smooth submanifold of $S^n$ for $n\ge 5$, then it's diffeomorphic to the standard $S^{n-1}$.

**EDIT**: Notice that, as Johannes Nordström points out in a comment below, if you fix the smooth structure on the target $S^n$ as well as the topological embedding whose image is a smooth submanifold, you automatically get a smooth structure on the source $S^{n-1}$, so the answer to your second question, as stated in your post, is yes, with no need to use any "big" result (no $h$-cobordism, no Schoenflies, etc.). In the previous version of this post, my question 2) was the negation of your original question, hence the answer was quite an overkill, while now it's more general.

Comment: Schoenflies isn't necessary for the very restricted question 2. Clearly the smooth structure of an embedded submanifold (with a particular choice of embedding) is determined by the smooth structure of the ambient manifold!

Comment: Oops, sorry. You are absolutely right; I will edit the question and things will hopefully fit.